# Is a local variable an lvalue when deducing its type using decltype?

Tags: c++

I am reading the [Wikipedia entry about decltype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype#Semantics), and I can't understand the following passage:

> Similarly to the sizeof operator, the operand of decltype is
> unevaluated.[11] Informally, the type returned by decltype(e) is
> deduced as follows:[2]
>
> 1. If the expression e refers to a variable in local or namespace scope, a static member variable or a function parameter, then the
>    result is that variable's or parameter's declared type
> 2. Otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e; if e is an xvalue, the result is T&&; otherwise, e is a
>    prvalue and the result is T.

it first says: "If the expression e refers to a variable in local or namespace scope", then it follows by "Otherwise, if e is an lvalue". For me it implies that a variable from local scope is not an lvalue. Am I right? - I always thought local variables are lvalues.

Maybe item 2 refers to case where we use `decltype((e))` - with double parentheses? I suppose this is what is said later in this wiki: "More formally, Rule 1 applies to unparenthesized id-expressions and class member access expressions."

Comment: *For me it implies that variable from local scope is not an lvalue.* That is not what it implies.  The otherwise applies to the scope of the variable, not its value category.

Comment: @fabian Faulty logic.  `std::string() = "foo";` also works, yet `std::string()` is not an lvalue. "Proof" comes from reading the standard.

Comment: @fabian assignment isn't proof of lvalueness: [`std::string{} = "this is an rvalue";`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea873a48e4a12580)

Comment: Now I see, the second will apply to case as : `std::string s; decltype(s="11") d=s;` and of course `std::string s; decltype((s)) d=s;`

Comment: Exactly, anything that has a name is an lvalue. The extra rule in `decltype` is basically a lie to make it easier to write code like `int x = 1; decltype(x) y = 2;`.

Comment: @rustyx - Nothing there is a lie. It simply goes from specific cases to more general ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For me it implies that variable from local scope is not an lvalue

No, that's not the correct way to read it. The list is not a bunch of mutually exclusive options. Some properties may overlap. When determining the type `decltype` produces, we are meant to apply the first item whose condition is satisfied. Think of it like an algorithm, a program to determine how `decltype` should behave (and since the standard is a technical specification, it pretty much is that).

```
if (e is the unparenthesized name of a variable ...)
  result = declared type of e
else if (e is an lvalue expression)
  result = type of e &
else if (e is an xvalue expression)
  result = type of e &&
else
  result = type of e
```

Obviously just like in a C++ program, more than one condition may be true. But (also like a C++ program) we simply go with the first branch whose condition is satisfied.